# sort list by createdDate golang

Tags: go

I have a function which returns model instance of Inspections and I want to `sort` it by `CreatedDate` but after I compile I've got

> cannot use inspections[i].CreatedDate (type string) as type bool in return argument

the `inspection.go` is

```
type Inspection struct {
    Id          int64               `db:"id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    CreatedDate string              `db:"created,omitempty" json:"created_date,omitempty"`
    Records     []*InspectionRecord `db:"-" json:"records,omitempty"`
    InspectionFields
}
```

and the `list.go` is

```
import (
    "sort"
)

func (s *Manager) list(fields *inspection.ItemIdField) (*inspection.InspectionHistoryResponse, error) {
    return s.listItemInspectionHistory(fields.ItemId)
}

func (s *Manager) listItemInspectionHistory(itemId string) (*inspection.InspectionHistoryResponse, error) {
    g := config.Client.Inspections()

    var inspections []*models.Inspection

    inspections, err := g.FindInspections(itemId)

    if err != nil {
        s.Log.Debugf("Can't find inspections of item with id %s", itemId)
        return nil, err
    }
    s.Log.Debugf("Found %d inspections for item with id %s", len(inspections), itemId)

    for _, inspection := range inspections {
        inspection.Records, err = g.FindRecords(inspection.Id)
        if err != nil {
            s.Log.Debugf("Can't find records for inspection with id %d", inspection.Id)
            return nil, err
        }
        s.Log.Debugf("Found %d records for inspection with id %d", len(inspection.Records), inspection.Id)
    }

    model := new(models.InspectionHistory)
    model.Inspections = inspections
    // sort by CreatedDate
    sort.Slice(inspections, func(i, j int) bool { return inspections[i].CreatedDate })

    return transform.InspectionHistoryModelToProtobufResponse(model)
}
```

The error is obvious but I'm a bit confused on how to resolve it, can someone please explain to me how to resolve this? thanks.

Comment: You're just returning one of the 2 strings to compare, you need to compare them and return a bool

Comment: so it's like this `sort.Slice(inspections, func(i, j int) bool { return inspections[i].CreatedDate < inspections[j].CreatedDate })`, and yes you are right

Comment: @JimB can you construct and answer so I can accept it

Comment: that only works if the dates are in a format that is lexicographically sortable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse the Date strings and compare them as [time.Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) instances

Assuming you have a valid date and they are on [RFC3339](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go?s=#L69), you may do the following

```
    sort.Slice(inspections, func(i, j int) bool {
        t1, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, inspections[i].CreatedDate)
        t2, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, inspections[j].CreatedDate)
        return t1.After(t2)
    })
```

Comment: I have, JimB helped with that hint, thanks for the example.